# Is Prediction the same as Compression?

Tags: prediction, compression

Just came across [this transcript](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/hAvGi9YAPZAnnjZNY/prediction-compression-transcript-1) that states:

> The principle is that prediction is the same thing as compression. And
> what that means is that whenever you have a prediction algorithm, you
> can also get a correspondingly good compression algorithm for data you
> already have, and vice versa.

Even though the article gives some examples, I would like to know some answers from this community on the question: Is Prediction the same as Compression?

Comment: According to the Information Bottleneck Method, it is

Answer (score 0):

Nontechnically, prediction (eg to predict) is the process of transforming an object.  The transformer often depends on summaries of information.  These summaries, or estimates, might be compression.

So, it seems that estimation might be compression, but prediction is not. I say might because you can describe a dataset by the dataset itself - that’s still an estimate, but not a compression. Usually, estimates are compressions.

Technically, a prediction is an estimate of a random variable.  To get that estimate requires estimation.  I don’t think though that this is the definition that the author is using.